# Issue with sliding a label in xypic using LyX

Tags: lyx, labels, xy-pic

I want to slide a label so I use the tex code

```
\xymatrix{A\ar^(.25){f}[r] & B}
```

Using directly this code as latex in LyX works, but I want to do the same thing in equations environment in LyX, what LyX is doing is putting all the `(.25){f}` part as superscript

```
\xymatrix{A\ar^{(.25){f}}[r] & B}
```

How can I avoid this problem without having to write raw latex in LyX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you could avoid those braces appearing in the LaTeX if you want to create the arrow directly in a math inset. You could avoid putting the whole xymatrix in TeX though by creating a macro and using that. In your preamble put:

`\newcommand{\myarr}[3]{\ar^(#1){#2}[#3]}`

Now in your equation inset you can use this like `\myarr{0.25}{f}{r}` (you'll have to type `\{` in order to get the brace pairs).

Better still you could combine this with LyX's math macro feature. This won't solve the problem of not being able to enter `\ar^(0.25)` — you'll still need to type TeX explicitly for that — but it can make it look a bit prettier. With the above command already in your preamble, create a math macro `\myrightar`, and in the second box (labelled "TeX") enter `\myarr{0.25}{#1}{r}` (you'll need to type a backslash before `#1` to get a parameter rather than literally a hash followed by a one). Now in the final box, labelled "LyX", you can enter whatever looks good and it won't affect the output. So you could put something like `\xrightarrow` and put `#1` in the top box (don't forget the backslash), and even put something like `\text{ }` in the bottom box to make it visually disappear.